# Connecting local users database with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

-> I want to use Identity server 4 as a central token generator for some clients.
-> Here my problem is I have implemented Identity server 4 with the help of docs, in the docs the IS4 is using its own database for users to login.
-> Can someone explain the way to connect to my own users database for login and token generation. (I'm using the latest version of IS4 and .net core).

Thanks in advance :)

Note:
I have tried all the things from docs
-> http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/8_aspnet_identity.html

Comment: _An ASP.NET Identity-based implementation is provided for managing the identity database for users of IdentityServer._, from the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html). In other words, all you need to do is replace this library with your custom code, as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers).

Comment: If you don't want to get into ASP.Net Identity perhaps it would help you to look at an older version of `AccountController` which did not use ASP.Net Identity. See https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/2.3.0/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs.  This version injects a simple user store using in  memory test users. You will need to implement your own user store..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AccountController` is a starting point for you to adapt to suit your own requirements.

This template uses ASP.NET Core Identity for user management.

Your choices are

- Migrate your users to use the Identity's table structure
- Provide a custom storage provider to ASP.Net Identity that uses your existing user tables ([Custom Storage Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2))
- Implement your own user management\storage service and change `AccountController` to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom database you want to connect to, you can implement the `IProfileService`. IdentityServer4 uses an instance of that interface to collect user details. Docs: [click](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html)

Comment: Can you explain me in brief. I wanted to connect my own users database to IS4 here.

Comment: @p.durgashankar implementing `IProfileService` is not enough because you'll need to address the fact that the `AccountController` is using ASP.Net Identity